# ydn-db - how to check if database exists at all

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ydn-db

I'm making a phonegap app and using ydn-db there.

The problem is I don't want to do `db = new ydn.db.Storage('db-name')` all the time because it creates a new database. Is there a way to check if my database exists already ?

Comment: Hi,r u using sqllite or websql ?

Comment: Umm...ydn-db provides a wrapper around indexeddb, websql and localstorage. In my case, I'm using websql

Comment: Pls accept ans if it will work for u ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can also use to check below code.

function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

```
// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');

}
```